# What is the meaning of the song "Solid Four"?

Tags: rhythm, time-signatures

There is a song by the Andrews Sisters from the 1940s whose [lyrics](http://www.lyrics.net/lyric/948667) talk about a difference between eight-beat rhythm and four-beat rhythm. For example:

> The boogie woogie was never like this,
>
> We've got a new beat that no
>   one can miss,
>
> if Boogie woogie sent like I think it did,
>
> Four to the bar will flip your lid.

I do not understand the difference, or why "Little Brown Jug" is a particularly good example of a song which is in four. I thought boogie woogie is in 4/4 time anyway? I would like examples of music which would help me to understand what two types of rhythm the song is talking about and how to hear the difference between them.

Comment: Little Brown Jug is actually in two time. It could be misconstrued as four, but the count would be very fast.

Comment: Enough with the edits on this question which change it from a specific question about jargon specific to a historical period and style of music, to a general uninteresting question about the difference between quarters and eighths.  The question was excellently put in its original form.

Comment: Back to the future...

Answer (score 3):

Like @Codeswitcher says, it's about the implied rhythm. The characteristic walking bass of a boogie woogie will imply a rhythm in eights. If you listen to Bounce me brother with a solid four, the piano in the beginning is emphasizing the quarter notes instead. You can imagine that song being played with a boogie woogie bassline to appreciate the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the expression "eight to the bar" is the term for the "beat" (well, that's what they called it) characteristic of boogie woogie, which is actually a style of **bass** accompaniment.  See [Wikipedia's page on boogie woogie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boogie-woogie) for a discussion of this and example bass lines.  The "eight to the bar" means it's all in eighth notes.  I'm gathering that the "solid four", in contrast, is a bass line in quarter notes.  I don't get the impression that by "beat" they meant anything to do with the drum part or the meter.